# incrementing counter in template with a condition is showing only the final count

Tags: alpine.js

Why isn't counter starting from 1 and not ending at 9 ?

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/alpinejs@3.13.2/dist/cdn.min.js"></script>
<div x-data="{counter: 1, data1: [33,34,56,78,13,45,69,32,76], data2: [13,68,99,13,88,97,32,12,87]}">
    <template x-for="(item, index1) in data1.filter(x => { if (x%2) { counter++; return true; } })" :key="index1">
        <div>
            <span x-text="item"></span>
            :
            <span x-text="counter"></span>
        </div>
    </template>
    <template x-for="(item, index2) in data2.filter(x => { if (x%2) { counter++; return true; } })" :key="index2">
        <div>
            <span x-text="item"></span>
            :
            <span x-text="counter"></span>
        </div>
    </template>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some concomitant reasons.

- The counter is initialized to 1 so, at the first increment it will be 2
- The Array.prototype.filter() function does not return value by value, but a complete array, so when the *for* loop evaluates the filterd array, the counter has been incremented by the total elements returned
- It seems that the AlpineJS engine itself tries to estimate when some data is changed and in this case it evaluates the *filter()* functions multiple times

You can realize this by inserting some *console.log()* and adding another *for* loop. Between loops I added additionals *console.log()* via *x-if*

```html
<script defer src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/alpinejs@3.12.3/dist/cdn.min.js"></script>

<div x-data="{counter: 1, data1: [33,34,56,78,13,45,69,32,76], data2: [13,68,99,13,88,97,32,12,87], data3: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 ,7, 8, 9],}">

    <template x-for="(item, index1) in data1.filter(x => { if (x%2) { counter++; console.log (x, counter); return true; } })" :key="index1">
        <div>
            <span x-text="item"></span>
            :
            <span x-text="counter"></span>
        </div>
    </template>

    <template x-if="console.log('----', counter)">
    </template>

    <template x-for="(item, index2) in data2.filter(x => { if (x%2) { counter++; console.log (x, counter); return true; } })" :key="index2">
        <div>
            <span x-text="item"></span>
            :
            <span x-text="counter"></span>
        </div>
    </template>

    <template x-if="console.log('====', counter)">
    </template>

    <template x-for="(item, index3) in data3.filter(x => { if (x%2) { counter++; console.log (x, counter); return true; } })" :key="index3">
        <div>
            <span x-text="item"></span>
            :
            <span x-text="counter"></span>
        </div>
    </template>

    <template x-if="console.log('**** **** ****', counter)">
    </template>
</div>
```